# Jetpack Compose and Hilt Conflict

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

For several days I've been trying to successfully build my project on which I was working on (Using Jetpack Compose), but when I updated the gradle build plugin and few more dependencies I've been unable to run the project correctly. There is some gradle version conflict with dagger-hilt dependencies and I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm using Canary BETA version of Android Studio.

Also here are all my gradle build files:

**Gradle Build Module App**:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mycomposedemo"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta07"
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.10'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta08"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta08"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta08"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha02"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-beta01'
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta08"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.0.0-beta08"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-beta08"

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.3.0"

    // Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"

    // Kotlin components
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0-native-mt"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0-native-mt"

    // Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.35.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.35.1"

    // Accompanist System UI Controller
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.8.1"
}
```

**Gradle Build (Project lvl)**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Error:**

> 'void
> com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTests$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
> com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'
>
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Exception is: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTests$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
>   com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
>   kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'   at
>   dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin.configureTransformASM(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:239)
>   at
>   dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin.configureHilt(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:79)
>   at
>   dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin.access$configureHilt(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:50)
>   at
>   dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin$apply$1.execute(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:57)
>   at
>   dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin$apply$1.execute(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:50)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:100)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:95)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:92)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.collections.CollectionFilter$1.execute(CollectionFilter.java:59)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:163)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.withType(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:205)
>   at
>   dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin.apply(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:55)
>   at
>   dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin.apply(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:50)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:177)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:51)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:272)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:157)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:156)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:127)
>   at
>   org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugins$0(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:129)
>   at
>   org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:185)
>   at
>   org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugins$1(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:127)
>   at
>   org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:127)
>   at
>   org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:123)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:117)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:723)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:150)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:69)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:226)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:164)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:66)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:90)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
>   at
>   org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
>   at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)

**Error2:**

> Unable to find method ''void
> com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTests$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
> com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'' 'void
> com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTests$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
> com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after
> a network connection timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) The state
> of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle
> daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [an issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2618) with Hilt Gradle Plugin `2.35.x` and Android Gradle Plugin `7.1.0-alpha01`.

This should be fixed with this [commit](https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/371a2c366a8c71b4bf5079d42e4a85578c8ddfc0) released with the Dagger `2.36`

Comment: Thank you for the information. To make my project work I've also commented out those two lines of code:

 composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta07"
//        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
//    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.10'