# Jetpack Compose and Hilt Conflict (NoSuchMethodError setContent)

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to develop Android application with Hilt and Jetpack Compose. Installed Gradle Hilt Plugin into Jetpack Compose application and getting an error.

Here are my gradle files:

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha09'
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version '1.5.30'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ddmukhin.exampleapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        compose true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.1.0-alpha02"
    }

    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'

//    Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

//    Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0-alpha03'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6"

//    Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.1'

//    Compose
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07'
    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.1.0-alpha02"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0-alpha09'
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0-alpha09'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30-RC'
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "ExampleApp"
include ':app'
```

My MainActivity class:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent{
            Greeting("Hello, world!")
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Greeting(text: String) {
        Text(text = text, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h2)
    }
}
```

And finally an error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
> setContent$default(Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;Landroidx/compose/runtime/CompositionContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
> in class Landroidx/activity/compose/ComponentActivityKt; or its super
> classes (declaration of
> 'androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt' appears in
> /data/app/com.ddmukhin.exampleapp-QlTRKYHfikMCdNcYBPcJIg==/base.apk)
> at com.ddmukhin.exampleapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:34)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

P.S. I've seen [Jetpack Compose and Hilt Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848538/jetpack-compose-and-hilt-conflict), but i've got another error + i did all steps mentioned in solution, but it didnt make sense.

Comment: have you found the solution? I run into the same issue.

Comment: The problem was in version conflict. Try to play with changing hilt and compose version (including downgrade)